Choosing the lowest price
Need help. Maybe someone knows. I want to create an indicator that will open positions only for buying. And I need this indicator during the purchase to choose from the list in Tradingview or from the crypto exchange the pair that lost the most interest for the previous day. How can this be implemented in pine script and is it possible at all? Thank you in advance.
Sorted list
I can't solve this issue on my own, because I don't have enough experience in writing scripts.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Pinescript cannot read from your watchlist. You need to select those tickers yourself in the script. You can use input.symbol() to select and modify the tickers.
After that, you need to use request.security to get the open and close prices from those securities. You want to get those values from the previous day.
Something like below:
[ticker_1_open, ticker_1_close] = request.security(ticker_1, "D", [open[1], close[1]])

Then you can calculate the change in price.
Tradingview cannot automatically execute trades on your exchange so you are going to need another tool for that. Something like 3Commas or Alertatron.
If this is for backtesting, your backtester will run on your chart's ticker. So, in order to backtest this, you need to implement your own backtester which should be able to handle price actions on different tickers. It is possible but might get quite complicated.

Thank you very much vitruvius. By the way, I wrote to you on March 14, 2024 at trading.vitruvius@gmail.com, but unfortunately I did not receive a reply.
